# How to retrieve BackColor of highlighted or selected Toolbar item using UFT?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, alm, uft14

[image]

I tried with following also...

```
Object.Items.item(3). BackColor
```

But it is throwing entire toolBar colour rather than highlighted colour.

Comment: We cannot know how this menu is built, so we cannot know how to query its dimensions, or color. Also, "Object.Items.item(3). BackColor" is a syntax error. Take the GUI spy and look at various item´s properties. If the color you are looking for is a property value, you can query it using .GetROProperty. If not, you might want to do a "direct API access" like the object reference you mentioned, but then it is totally dependent on your insights of the inner structure of the app.